# Multiple constrains single generics parameter

Tags: c#, generics

Here is an example of declaring a **single parameter generics class** with **single constraints**.

```
public class TestClass<T> : ITestClass<T> where T : Teacher
```

I am looking for a way to declare the **TestClass** with **multiple constraints**. Where I will be able to use an interface for different classes.

**How can I do something like this?...**

```
public class TestClass<T> : ITestClass<T> where T : Teacher, Student, new()
```

My classes look like

```
public class Teacher{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
}

public class Student{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Roll { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No, because the constraint isnt either or but all of the constraint must be met. Use a base class and use this base class as the contraint

Comment: Or create an interface that `Teacher` and `Student` both implement.  I would assume you need to get at `Name` as that's the only common property.